# in this Flush vs flush who wins + pairs in the 2 hands?

Tags: probability, pocket-pair

**pleaase explain who wins ? and WHY ?? THANKS ALL :)**
[image]

Comment: What game is this?

Answer (score 1):

There are six community cards.  What is this game, six pack?  If so, it isn't clear to me which cards are in the 2, 4, 8 and 10 o'clock position.

If it's just a version of texas hold-em where you can use any of the cards between your hole cards and the community cards, then:

The best 5 card hand that Player 1 can make is K:hearts Q:hearts 7:hearts 6:hearts 4:hearts.

The best 5 card hard that Player 2 can make is K:hearts 8:hearts 7:hearts 6:hearts 4:hearts.

Player 1 would win, because the second card (Q) beats Player 2's second card (8).

Comment: do the pairs count ? and did you them :) 
thnx for the reply

Comment: @RamzyWahid Nope, pairs don't count.  Only the best ranked hand you can make from 5 cards count, which in this case is a flush.